# Close application on press of GlobalShortcut keys when application is in focus

Tags: javascript, electron

I have made a application that comes in focus when I press the Global Shortcut keys when it is not in focus. I want the application to close with the press of same Global Shortcut key, if currently it is in focus.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`win.isFocused()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winisfocused) flag like this:

```
globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+F', () => {
    if (window.isFocused()) {
        window.hide();
    } else {
        window.show();
    }
});
```

So if the window is hidden then pressing the shortcut will show it and if the window is in focus then pressing the shortcut will hide it.

[`win.isFocused`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winisfocused) Docs.